# Nuxt3 route with file extension

Tags: nuxt3

I need to show a component when user tries to access image, say domain.com/images/ID.jpg (where id is dynamic).

I've tried with servermiddleware but I'm only getting 404's and can't seem to get anything logged.

What I'm trying:

```
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
    serverMiddleware: [
     { path: '/images/:id.jpg', handler: resolve(__dirname, 'server-middleware/jpg.js') },
    ],
```

But this is not working. Is there any way to achieve this? I